# How to fix Firebase admin verifyIdToken is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm working through [Lee Robinson's React 2025 course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OndBtUUD8XE&list=PL6bwFJ82M6FXgctyoWXqj7H0GK8_YIeF1&index=7) and I'm experiencing an issue while trying to verify an ID token through Firebase admin. The closest issue I can find is [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752) but the solutions didn't work for me.

The error I got is:

```
TypeError: firebase_admin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.auth.verifyIdToken is not a function
at __webpack_exports__.default (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/notes.js:10:65)
at apiResolver (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:7)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:63:403)
at async Object.fn (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:55:530)
at async Router.execute (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:24:67)
at async DevServer.run (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:65:1023)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/Alfred/Documents/Alfred/Coding/augment-notes/augment-notes/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:33:450)
```

Here are the relevant files:

**firebase-admin.js**

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      project_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
      client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    }),
    databaseURL: '<my database url, removed for this post>',
  });
}

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

**notes.js**

```
import { getUserNotes } from '@/lib/db-admin';
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { uid } = await auth.verifyIdToken(req.headers.token);
  const { notes } = await getUserNotes(uid);

  res.status(200).json({ notes });
};
```

I don't think it's an issue with my Firebase admin SDK setup because I can fetch data from the database if I remove the `verifyIdToken` method and insert a `uid` directly.

If I should provide more information, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone pointed out to me that the import in notes.js should be a relative file path import rather than importing the node package. That fixed the error!

So it should have been:

`import { auth } from ‘@/utils/firebase-admin’;` in notes.js.